# Returning a SUM from DISTINCT columns in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still fairly new to SQL and have been learning as I go. Hopefully I can learn something new from the wise wizards here at StackOverflow.

What I have:
I have a table in which I need to run a query on. The table in total has 6 columns (including primary key).

```
|  ID  |  orderNumber  |  partNumber  |  name  |  qty  |  unitPrice  |
```

Fairly self-explanatory so far.

What I need to do:
I am needing to query this table to get the SUM of the qty for each partNumber. This is to get a current on-hand of products.
Using my basic knowledge (and some Google-fu) I thought I could do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT partNumber, name, SUM(qty) as qty  
FROM [Bulk]  
GROUP BY partNumber, name  
ORDER BY partNumber
```

But this still returns duplicate partNumbers with that order's individual qty, like so:

```
ID | partNumber | name          | qty
---|------------|---------------|--------
1  | 428154     | '22" Monitor' | 5
1  | 428154     | '22" Monitor' | 8
1  | 428154     | '22" Monitor' | 2
1  | 428154     | '22" Monitor' | 4
1  | 428154     | '22" Monitor' | 1
```

I've read a bit about doing a PARTITION, but am not sure if that is what I need, or how to even implement that. Could someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

SAMPLE ROWS

```
ID | orderNumber   | partNumber  | name           | qty
---|---------------|-------------|----------------|-------
1  | 45751         | 104579      | Wireless Mouse | 10  
2  | 45718         | 104579      | Wireless Mouse | 5  
3  | 45795         | 104579      | Wireless Mouse | 3  
4  | 44354         | 104631      | Keyboard       | 18  
5  | 49765         | 104631      | Keyboard       | 1  
6  | 48789         | 104631      | Keyboard       | 9
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
partNumber | name             | qty
-----------|------------------|--------
104579     | Wireless Mouse   |  18  
104631     | Keyboard         |  28
```

RESULTS WITHOUT DISTINCT

```
partNumber | name             | qty  
-----------|------------------|--------  
464968621  | Footstand        |  1  
464968621  | Footstand        |  12   
538898644  | Wall Mount       |  12   
564848989  | IP Phone         |  4   
564848989  | IP Phone         |  1
```

Comment: You should not be using `DISTINCT` when you are aggregating and using `GROUP BY`

Comment: Can you please add the Column names in your sample rows and the desired output

Comment: Those are random numbers that are assigned to the parts that are then placed in to this [Bulk] table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `DISTINCT` from your query. It should look like this:

```
SELECT
   partNumber,
   name,
   SUM(qty) as qty  
FROM
   [Bulk]  
GROUP BY
   partNumber,
   name  
ORDER BY
   partNumber
```

If, as you say, the names for the same part may differ *and you don't care which name is returned*, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT
   partNumber,
   MAX(name) as name,
   SUM(qty) as qty  
FROM
   [Bulk]  
GROUP BY
   partNumber
ORDER BY
   partNumber
```

**Using your own data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Bulk
(ID int, orderNumber INT, partNumber INT, name VARCHAR(30), qty INT)

INSERT INTO #Bulk
VALUES
(1,45751,104579,'Wireless Mouse',10),
(2,45718,104579,'Wireless Mouse',5),
(3,45795,104579,'Wireless Mouse',3),
(4,44354,104631,'Keyboard',18),
(5,49765,104631,'Keyboard',1),
(6,48789,104631,'Keyboard',9);

SELECT
   partNumber,
   name,
   SUM(qty) as qty  
FROM
   [#Bulk]  
GROUP BY
   partNumber,
   name  
ORDER BY
   partNumber;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Doing this returns multiple part numbers.  Please see OP for results.

Comment: In your `Sample Rows` you are calling those data "Order Number" but in your `Desired Output` you call it "Part Number". Which is it?

Comment: Just saw that, thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected the OP.

Comment: If the names are different, even slightly, will that cause the results to not condense the partNumbers?

Comment: You are grouping by a `partNumber` and a `name` - if either are different, then it will return a separate record.

Comment: I see...and I am also seeing the importance of not cleaning up the data as much as I did when posting this. Some of the names are slightly different from one another, so this would be why I am still getting separate records. Is there a way to pull the name for a partNumber while still condensing them down?

Comment: If the names are different for the same `partNumber` - which name would you want to use? Does it matter?

Comment: No, it would not matter which one it uses. The names are composed of the orderNumber and a description of the part. But I need the name in there for a part description.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for your help and patience! This works beautifully!